# React-native-ble-plx: Is it possible for configuring indicate as a standard protocol instead of notify?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

I have integrated the library(react-native-ble-plx) in my app(central device) and my peripheral device supports indication. However, whenever I send a command the first time, the react native ble plx seems to be disabling indication and all the subsequent commands are sent as a notify.
Based on what I read, it(react-native-ble-plx) prefers the notify standard in place of the indicate.

[image]

Is there a way I can make my app still use indicate without disabling it , in both Android and iOS?